# How to configure browser based vlc plug in for linux

Tags: html, plugins, video-streaming, vlc

I have created html page that helps to play video on All Browser on windows, but when i tried it on linux browser it say required to install plugin to play video, but i want to make browser to automatically install vlc-plug in on linux browser and play video.

**Code :**

```
<object classid="clsid:9BE31822-FDAD-461B-AD51-BE1D1C159921" codebase="http://downloads.videolan.org/pub/videolan/vlc/latest/win32/axvlc.cab" width="400" height="300" id="vlc" events="True">
    <param name="Src" value="http://www.medicodb.com/Video/opt.DAT"></param>
    <param name="ShowDisplay" value="True" ></param>
    <param name="AutoLoop" value="no"></param>
    <param name="AutoPlay" value="yes"></param>
    <embed type="application/x-google-vlc-plugin" name="vlcfirefox" autoplay="yes" loop="no" width="400" height="300" target="http://www.medicodb.com/Video/opt.DAT"></embed>
</object>
```

Please help me out with this problem...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that on Linux. There are at least 3 different software management systems on the different distributions and they all work differently. All you can and should do is prompting the user to ask to install the VLC plugin, if available for her respective distribution.